# TSQL: Variable scope and EXEC()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @test varchar(20)
set @test = 'VALUE'

exec('
select '+@test+'
')
```

This returns:

> Invalid column name 'VALUE'.

Is there an alternate method to display the variable value on the select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cmsjr has a point about not needing exec for this.  But assuming you're posting a simplified version of the problem and exec is a requirement:

There's no column named "value" because there's no table.  If you just want it to print `value`, you need to encase it in quotes so it looks like a string literal inside the call to exec:

```
exec(' select ''' + @test + ''' ')
```

Comment: Good point.  Where will the data for your @test variable come from?  Even if it's a somewhat trusted source, you could be creating a 2nd order vulnerability.

Comment: I need to create dynamic tsql to select between 5 different sources within the same sql instance. The variables will come from date pre-calculations done in the same sp that runs the exec command prior to executing it.

Comment: if you're certain you're only using a portion of a datetime data type as your additional parameter, you should be okay.  Also look into sp_executesql

Comment: Rather than using dynamic SQL, you might be better off using a view across all of your data sources using UNION with a hard-coded value in the view to determine the source from which the data comes.

Answer (score 8):

The clean alternative is to use [sp_executesql()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and its ability to deal with parameterized statements:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @parm NVARCHAR(100)

SET @stmt = N'SELECT @val'        /* statement definition */
SET @parm = N'@val VARCHAR(20)'   /* parameters definition */
SET @test = 'VALUE'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt, @parm, @val = @test
```

Yields:

```
(no column name)
VALUE
```

Comment: How would the from statement look like if I wanted to dynamically select the database using another variable?

Comment: Your question did not seem to go into this direction for me. It either looked like a variable scoping problem or a semantics/syntax misunderstanding on your side. I covered the former option, Joel Coehoorn covered the latter.

Comment: The English documentation is here.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Exec in this context
If you are doing a direct assignment you can use

```
Set @test = 'VALUE'
```

and to display the value just select it without assigning a value

```
Select @test
```